# How can I write Pass or Fail result in console for submit button click (Selenium)

Tags: java, selenium

```
driver.findElement(By.name("RNSCategoryFilter1$btnsubmit")).click();
```

For above step, how can I write test pass/fail result in console?
e.g. for below code I have wirte if...else.. condition to identify Pass or Fail result. Same I want to write Pass and Fail condition for above code.

```
List<WebElement> urls = driver.findElement(By.id("DataNewsFeeds")).findElements(By.tagName("a"));
            for (WebElement urlclick : urls) {
                if(urlclick.getText().contains(toolURL))
                {
                    driver.navigate().to(toolURL);
                    url = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(url)
            {
                System.out.println("TC-4 Passed: '" +toolURL+ "' Clicked");

            }
            else
                System.out.println("TC-4 Failed: '" +toolURL+ "' not found");
```

Comment: Sorry - but it is very difficult to understand your problem. Please edit your question and come up with a clear question and a problem-definition.

Comment: @Melvin thanks for your suggestion, I have edited my question and hope everyone will understand better.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose after click operation on button, Button got disappear or something is happening on the page by reference of that you can do something like  -

```
boolean clickOperationsAssert = driver.findElement(By.name("locator_of_element_if_selected_after_click_operation")).isSelected();  

driver.findElement(By.name("locator_of_new_element_after_click_on_button")).isDisplayed();  

driver.findElement(By.name("locator_of element_enabled_after_click_operation")).isEnabled();
```

`isSelected()`, `isDisplayed()`, `isEnabled()` methods will return Boolean value which you can assert.

```
if(clickOperationsAssert){
      System.out.println("TC-5 Passed: '" +toolbutton+ "' Clicked");
}
else{
     System.out.println("TC-5 Passed: '" +toolbutton+ "' not found or not able to click");
}
```